# How to read and write correctly REG_DWORD into registry?

Tags: java, windows, registry

I was able to read and write String values,but having problem with REG_DWORD type values.

I am Trying to read and write the registry key

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
"DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled"=dword:00000001

Below is the code i tried to use for reading the key

public class ReadRegistry
{

```
public static final String readRegistry(String location, String key){
    try {
        // Run reg query, then read output with StreamReader (internal class)
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query " +
                '"'+ location + "\" /v " + key);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        reader.start();
        process.waitFor();
        reader.join();

        // Parse out the value
        // String[] parsed = reader.getResult().split("\\s+");

        String s1[];
        try{
         s1=reader.getResult().split("REG_SZ|REG_DWORD");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return " ";
        }
       //MK System.out.println(s1[1].trim());

        return s1[1].trim();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return null;
}
 static class StreamReader extends Thread {
    private InputStream is;
    private StringWriter sw= new StringWriter();

    public StreamReader(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int c;
            while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
                //System.out.println(c);
                sw.write(c);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return sw.toString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: PLease show your code!

Comment: Added code to read the key, but don't know how to write the key.

Comment: @OldProgrammer any util class available to read and write the key of type REG_DWORD ?